# Getting casting errors with JLabel and JButton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jlabel, classcastexception

I'm making a card game, and the player can either click on the draw button to draw a card or play a card. 
Problem is, whenever I click draw it gives me casting errors but my cast to `JLabel` is only if they click on a card.

Error only happens when I click on draw.

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) 
    {
        double x = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getX();
        double y = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getY();
        if(x>=draw.getX()&&x<=draw.getX()+draw.getWidth() && y>=draw.getY() && y<=draw.getY()+draw.getHeight())
        {
            //change later so anonymous
            say("\nPlayer "+UNO.getturn()+" drew a "+UNO.getdeckontop());
            UNO.draw();
            UNO.nextturn();
            smalllennie();
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            JLabel label = (JLabel)arg0.getSource();
            int index = currentdeck.indexOf(label);
```

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException:
  javax.swing.JButton cannot be cast to javax.swing.JLabel  
at Graphic.mousePressed(Graphic.java:146)
```

Comment: Why are you using a `MouseListener` for a `JButton`? You should use an `ActionListener` for those as they are already designed to fire action events when clicked. Also, as someone else stated on your previous question, you can get the x and y coordinates of your `MouseEvent` by doing `arg0.getX()`/`arg0.getXOnScreen()` and `arg0.getY()`/`arg0.getYOnScreen()`rather than using `MouseInfo`.

Comment: okay thanks, I'll try that!

Comment: You are being careless with what you're adding the listener to. If the listener expects the source to be a JLabel, then only add the listener to a JLabel. Likewise if your listener expects the source to be a JButton, then only add it to a JButton. And yes, buttons in general should use ActionListeners preferentially over MouseListeners (although there are a few exceptions to this).

Comment: yes, I see now. Thank y'all so much!

Comment: When asking questions, please add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).